# How to get all the clauses defined/loaded from a file in Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

I am using SWI Prolog and am surprised to find no obvious way to do this in Prolog. What I'm after is something similar to clause/2 but allows uninstantiated first argument (and is specific to the clauses in a given file, ie I don't want the entire Prolog library!). Here is what I wrote to find all the clauses

```
clauseX(H,B) :-
    current_predicate(P/Arity),
    functor(H,P,Arity),
    absolute_file_name('filname.pl', AbsFileName),
    predicate_property(H, file(AbsFileName)),
    clause(H,B).
```

Is there a more concise way of doing this?

Comment: Note that most Prolog system only allow you to use `clause/2` on dynamic predicates. In the specific case of recent SWI-Prolog versions, you can use `clause/2` on static predicates as long the `protect_static_code` flag is set to `false`.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've been able to shorten it somewhat, the first two literals aren't required, this will return clauses in the file filename.pl

```
clauseX(H,B) :-
    absolute_file_name('filname.pl', AbsFileName),
    predicate_property(H, file(AbsFileName)),
    clause(H,B).
```

However I am still concerned about the efficiency of this and whether it has to consult the file every time clauseX is called